# Install flash for Chrome on linux without root?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, flash

I'm on a workstation here and the admins haven't enabled Flash for Chrome, but it does work under Firefox. Is there some way I could config Chrome to point at the `nswrapper_32_64.libflashplayer.so` that Firefox is using or copy it to my home directory somewhere and have it working?

Running Chrome 13 on RHEL6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome includes Flash player. You may [just need to enable it](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/839/cpsid_83950.html#main__I_am_unable_to_view_Flash_content__How_do_I_get_Flash_Player_to_turn_on_).

*Chromium* does **not** include Flash player. If it does not recognize the same plugins Firefox does (and it should), you can try putting all relevant files into `~/.mozilla/plugins`, [one of the directories searched by chromium](http://codesearch.google.com/#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/webkit/plugins/npapi/plugin_list_posix.cc&exact_package=chromium&q=/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins&type=cs&l=145).

Comment: Chrome doesn't always include Flash player, but symlinking the flash plugin into ~/.mozilla/plugins did the trick.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't want to run the flash installer in root and making a ~/.mozilla/plugins (in my home fo folder and dropping the .so file into worked like a charm).